# Maiúsculas e minúsculas no PHP

Tags: php

Estou tendo um problema um tanto quanto incomum (ou comum não sei).
Tenho um campo de cadastro de e-mail. O usuário adiciona um e-mail, o sistema verifica se o e-mail já existe no banco de dados, se não ele cadastra, se sim, ele não cadastra.

Acontece que se o usuário diferenciar uma letra do e-mail para maiúscula o sistema interpreta o e-mail diferentemente.
Por exemplo, existe um e-mail no BD: "marcos@email.com", se um usuário tentar cadastrar o e-mail "Marcos@email.com" o sistema permite.

O que posso fazer para desativar essa verificação maiúscula/minúscula? Ou não é preciso? o sistema tem de fazer essa verificação mesmo.

Comment: Considerações que deve fazer: Se eu enviar o e-mail para `X` será o mesmo que eu enviar para `x`? Se sim, você deverá tratar para considerá-las equivalentes. Outra é: importará para o usuário se cadastrar `X` e armazenar no banco `x`?

Comment: Você leu a RFC para saber quais partes fazem diferença? Dependendo do servidor Marcos@ e marcos@ podem realmente ser contas diferentes. à direita do at (@) aplicam-se as regras normais pra domain name. à esquerda, é permitido que a implementação faça como achar melhor.

Comment: Mas isso não seria meio errado, pois tipo, se eu sou uma pessoa pública que recebo muitos e-mails no endereço marcos@gmail.com. Se o cara digita no celular o e-mail ele já deixa a primeira letra maiúscula, logo Marcos@gmail.com, assim os e-mails que eram pra mim são endereçados para outro, acho que não existe um servidor de e-mail que permita isso seilá.

Comment: É melhor desenvolver na certeza do que na especulação... quantidade de bugs certamente diminui.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais fácil já seria no **INSERT** tratar todas as strings que usa-se para comparações (no PHP, pois no banco, dependendo qual usa não é case sensitive).

---

Complementando o dito pelo Lucas, as formas mais fáceis seriam:

[strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php): converte uma string para **minúsculas**

Exemplo:

```
$str = "EmailExemplo@email.com";
$str = strtolower($str);
echo $str; // Resultado: emailexemplo@email.com
```

[strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtoupper.php): converte uma string para **maiúsculas**:

Exemplo:

```
$str = "EmailExemplo@email.com";
$str = strtoupper($str);
echo $str; // Resultado: EMAILEXEMPLO@EMAIL.COM
```

Comment: Obrigado. Antes mesmo de suas respostas eu já tinha pesquisado e resolvido o problema, mas muuuuuuuuuuito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função strtolower() para converter toda a string para minúsculo e fazer a consulta no banco com retorno dessa função.

`$email = strtolower($email);`

Comment: Obrigado. Antes mesmo de suas respostas eu já tinha pesquisado e resolvido o problema, mas muuuuuuuuuuito obrigado!!!